# Ubuntu Software RAID 1 with NTFS weird volumes on RAID Array

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid, mdadm, 64-bit, raid1

I'm trying to mirror two secondary 2TB HDDs with RAID 1 with 1 big NTFS partition and am coming cross something that looks weird to me, although it could just be my complete ignorance because this is the first time I've setup a RAID before.

I partitioned both HDDs with NTFS, because I want to share the drives with Windows computers on the network. I selected both HDDs in the Ubuntu Disks utility and created a RAID 1. Under RAID Arrays shows my 2 TB RAID Array, but the volumes are laid out in a weird way:

```
Free Space - 112 GB
Partition 1 - 871 GB Unknown
Partition 2 - 372 GB Unknown
Free Space - 645 GB
```

When I try deleting the partition 1 it says(It gives a similar error when I try to delete Partition 2 as well.):

```
Error deleting partition /dev/md127p1: Command-line `parted --script "/dev/md127" "rm 1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Error: /dev/md127: unrecognized disk label(udisks-error-quark, 0).
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just needed to use GParted to create a new partition table on md127.